# Windows launcher created using Install4J is very slow to start

Tags: windows, performance, qt, install4j, launcher

Recently whilst evaluating `Install4j`, I found that the Windows launcher, generated using the options `GUI` application (`Allow -console parameter`, `Uses SWT or QT`), was very slow in starting up.

Leading to click on the launcher multiple times.

Thereafter if the application was shut and restarted via the launcher the startup was much faster.

Are there ways to speed up initial startup? Are any of the chosen options causing it to slow down, for e.g. `QT or SWT` or the `Allow -console parameter` option?

Comment: Can you profile it and see where the slowness comes from?

Comment: I have resolved it by deselecting the sub-options under GUI (`QT or SWT` and the `Allow -console parameter`)

Comment: Just for future references how would we profile it on a Windows or MacOSX machine?

Comment: On Windows, JProfiler has an integration wizard for exe4j/install4j launchers. Btw, if you use SWT, you have to upgrade to 7.0.3, there was an important fix for SWT on macOS.

Comment: Still thinking about moving to 7.0.3 but have refrained from using SWT option or -console option for the moment, do you recommend using this as a default? Not much information about this is available if you could lead me to more details will help when choosing in the future.

Comment: The SWT option is required if you use an SWT app, it passes the -XstartOnFirstThread option to the VM. The "Allow -console parameter" should have no effect in this respect.